# Multithreading Synchronization in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, synchronization

Hi I am running multiple threads in my program with each thread contaning an array of 6 elements. I have added synchronize in my run method for the thread but only the first thread is synchronised in terms of displaying the array orderly from 1 to 6.

```
/* My run method for the thread */
public synchronized void run(){
    int from = St7.stt[acnt].getCf();
    int to = St7.stt[acnt].getCt();
    int inc = St7.stt[acnt].getCi();
    threadsRunning++; // We now have more threads 
    this.threadId = threadsRunning;
    active = true;
    try{
        int loop = from;
        while (active && loop <= to){

            System.out.println(text + " Counter: " + St7.stt[acnt].getCounter() + ".");
            System.out.println();
            Thread.sleep(sleep);
            loop=loop+inc;
        }
```

Comment: Can you more clearly explain the question?

Comment: So what's the problem? What output are you getting and what output are you hoping to get?

Comment: Also: making a thread's `run()` method `synchronised` achieves exactly nothing. The method is already, by definition, being run on its own thread.

Comment: have explained hopefully more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you want the threads' results in the same order they're dispatched, if that's correct probably the [Callable](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/get_netbeans_6) interface could help you: it allows you to execute in multiple threads but also you are able to get the return of each thread in the order you've executed them (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632960/java-executorservice-with-callables-invokeall-and-future-get-results-in)).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, and the poor variable naming doesn't help, but it seems you're create N instance of a StudentThread  class, which all have their `run()` method synchronized.

That won't prevent multiple threads to invoke the run method concurrently, since they're all synchronized on a *separate* object. To have mutual exclusion, all the threads must synchronize on a *unique* object, which should encapsulate the shared state that must be protected from concurrent access.